# How to add omniture adobe analytics to angular 4 application?

Tags: angular, analytics, adobe-analytics, angular4-forms

I am trying to add omniture adobe analytics to my angular 4 application. Can some one please help me with this ? I am not able to find any documentation currently for the same.

Comment: if your tracking needs are basic, you might consider using [Angulartics](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics) or [Angularytics](https://github.com/mgonto/angularytics)

Comment: You should normally add DTM in header section and use direct call rules for tracking.